# What means $B^\top B$ in a matrix?

Tags: matrices, notation, transformation

The question is: determine $B^\top B$ with matrix:

$$B=\begin{pmatrix}1&2&-1\\-2&3&-5\end{pmatrix}$$

I don't understand what they are asking.

Comment: $B^T$ is (probably) the *transpose* of the matrix $B$. Just google it.

Comment: yes but, with the following matrix, what is the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$B^T=\begin{pmatrix}1&-2\\2&3\\-1&-5\end{pmatrix}$  $B=\begin{pmatrix}1&2&-1\\-2&3&-5\end{pmatrix}$,$B^TB=\begin{pmatrix}1&-2\\2&3\\-1&-5\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&2&-1\\-2&3&-5\end{pmatrix}=$